# In Kdenlive, how to select an area for render?

Tags: kdenlive, render

In Kdenlive's render settings I can choose the option to render "selected zone".

How do I select the zone?

"Shift + left click" enables a box selection. However it only selects whole clips, so this approach does not work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the keys "i" for "start" and "o" for "end" to create the selection. They use the current frame position.

---

Example:

Move the playhead to frame 190 and press "i". Move it to 390 and press "o".

This creates a selection with beginning at the frame 190 and end at 390.

Comment: Thanks a lot, we searched this for way too much time ^^" Isn't there a more intuitive solution?

Comment: Part of the issue is that kdenlive uses many video editing jargon terms.  In this case, `i` and `o` are mnemonic, representing a video's "in" and "out" points.

Comment: The same function is available from the menu under "Monitor → Set Zone In" and "Monitor → Set Zone Out".

Comment: Thank you! Such a time saver!

Answer (score 1):

another approach that uses mouse is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyMZc.jpg

in other words, when you only need to adjust the zone out, you can drag this UI element or drag the middle.

Sorry, I cannot make the mini video viewable inline.

Comment: This is hardly usable on a long project when we don't even know where it's located